# How do i get an ODBC refresh to trigger vb code

Tags: excel, vba, events, odbc, refresh

I have an odbc connection named "Parcel Picks by Hour" that is on an auto run timer every 15 minutes. I want to run an script that sends an email with the updated data after the refresh event is complete. all codes I have found were unsuccessful. since the timer is already built into the ODBC i dont want a code that refreshes the connection then sends an email i just want the refresh to trigger the code to run.

Comment: Could you add a litte more detail about the connection, and the code that doesn't suit.  I would like to know what you've tried, save me trying something already known not to work :)

Comment: Its an oracle database connection that runs  a basic sql every 15 minutes. i want some code that will trigger on that connection refreshing. its a report for a peak season in my warehouse that runs open orders. once the data is refreshed i have a macro that will email all of my higher ups  while i am not here. i just cant figure out the code to trigger the macro. i have tried on change macros but there are a few connections so i end up spamming emails every 15 minutes.

Comment: Have you looked at event sinking?  You can use `withevents` to create a "custom" connection.  I'll add an answer, on how to do, but you'll need to play with it yourself as it will just be a thought, as you've posted no code, so cant see the connection set up.

Comment: i dont think that is the route i need to go, the connection is already established and working fine. Also when trying to run this code i get user-defined type not defined error. ill post the connection details below.

Comment: DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};SERVER=********;UID=*********;PWD=********;DBQ=*******;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;XSM=Default;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=Me;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=60000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;

Comment: Yes, so you set the connection up using my code below, where your connection string is your oracle one.

Comment: No the code below did not work. i think i may not have a reference active or something. the connection above i set up last year.

Answer (score 0):

NOT AN ANSWER AN IDEA

Create a class like so, ive called mine `clsCustomConnection`

```
Private WithEvents cn As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub Initialise(cnADO As ADODB.Connection)
    Set cn = cnADO
End Sub

Private Sub cn_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, _
                        adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, _
                        ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)

    '   Email function
    MyEmailFunction ("VBAEventExample.co.uk")

End Sub
```

Then in a normal module, something like so

```
Public CustomADOConnection As clsCustomConnection

Sub setupADOconnection()

    Dim ADOConn1 As New ADODB.Connection

    '   Set up connection
    ADOConn1.ConnectionString = ""
    ADOConn1.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    '   Sink to custom connection
    Set CustomADOConnection = New clsCustomConnection
    CustomADOConnection.Initialise ADOConn1

End Sub
```